# Getting facebook friends name

Tags: objective-c, facebook

i'm using this code for getting all the logged in facebook friends name and id. The problem is it does not seem to get the names. It returns (null) as name and the correct id. Why does it not get the names, but gets the id?

```
 FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends?fields=installed" parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"];



 [friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                               NSDictionary* result,
                                                               NSError *error) {
 NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
 NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
      for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {
           NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ with id %@", friend.name, friend.id);

       }



 }];
```

Comment: What are you getting in  NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ with id %@", friend.name, friend.id);

Answer (score 1):

> `FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends?fields=installed"
>   parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"];`

You are specifically asking for *only* the `installed` field here, so you get only that (and the id, which you always get in any case).

So add the other fields you want to that request path, f.e. `me/friends?fields=installed,name` to also get the name of the friends.